# parallelized loops but sequential results in C with OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, hpc

The part C code and questions are below, `piece_list_t` and `grid_t` are struct type, and `grid_t->cells` is a pointer:

```
#define GO_LEFT_TO_RIGHT (0)

typedef struct { 
  int tab[4];
  char name[LABEL_LEN+1];
} piece_t;

/* Keep all the pieces and the number of them together. */

typedef struct {
  piece_t *pieces;
  int numpieces;
} piece_list_t;

/* A cell in the grid knows its north and west tabs.  Since this cell is
   expected to be in a grid, its east tab is the same as the west tab of the
   next cell to the right.  Its south tab is the same as the north tab of the 
   cell immediately below. 

    When we define our grid, cell entry (0, 0) will be the top left
    corner with the "y" values increasing as you go down the page.
*/

typedef struct {
  int north;
  int west;
  piece_t *piece;
} cell_t;

typedef struct {
  cell_t **cells;
  int numcols;
  int numrows;
} grid_t;

/* Have a function that traverses a row or a column, trying to fill in
   pieces.*/

void 
fill_any_dir( grid_t *grid, piece_list_t *piece_list, 
              int start_col, int start_row, int inc_index )
{
  int j;
  int found;
  int row, col;
  int col_inc[] = {1, 0, -1, 0};
  int row_inc[] = {0, 1, 0, -1};
  int count;

  row = start_row;
  col = start_col;

  /* Loop through the entire column / row and stop when we hit an edge or a 
     puzzle grid cell that is already filled in. */

  while ((row >= 0) && (col >= 0) && (row < grid->numrows) && 
         (col < grid->numcols) &&(grid->cells[col][row].piece == NULL)) {

    /* Ensure that we're ready for the piece by making sure that at least
       two tabs are defined. */

    count = 0;
    if (grid->cells[col][row].north != NO_PIECE_INDEX) count++;
    if (grid->cells[col][row].west != NO_PIECE_INDEX) count++;
    if (grid->cells[col][row+1].north != NO_PIECE_INDEX) count++;
    if (grid->cells[col+1][row].west != NO_PIECE_INDEX) count++;

    if (count >= 2) {

      /* Search the set of pieces for what will go in this grid position. */

      found = NO_PIECE_INDEX;
      for (j = 0; (j < grid->numcols * grid->numrows) && (found == NO_PIECE_INDEX); j++) { 

        /* I will find the first piece whose tabs match the defined tabs of
           the grid cell.  This will find the unique pieces _if_ the grid
           cell has at least two adjacent tabs that are not -1. */

        if (
            ((grid->cells[col][row].north == NO_PIECE_INDEX) || 
             (grid->cells[col][row].north == piece_list->pieces[j].tab[NORTH_TAB])) &&
            ((grid->cells[col+1][row].west == NO_PIECE_INDEX) || 
             (grid->cells[col+1][row].west == piece_list->pieces[j].tab[EAST_TAB])) &&
            ((grid->cells[col][row+1].north == NO_PIECE_INDEX) || 
             (grid->cells[col][row+1].north == piece_list->pieces[j].tab[SOUTH_TAB])) &&
            ((grid->cells[col][row].west == NO_PIECE_INDEX) || 
             (grid->cells[col][row].west == piece_list->pieces[j].tab[WEST_TAB]))
        )
        {
          found = j;
        }
      }

      /* When we get the piece, fit it into the grid and update the tabs of
         the grid for all surrounding grid cells. */

      if (found != NO_PIECE_INDEX) {
        grid->cells[col][row].piece = &(piece_list->pieces[found]);
        grid->cells[col][row].north = piece_list->pieces[found].tab[NORTH_TAB];
        grid->cells[col+1][row].west = piece_list->pieces[found].tab[EAST_TAB];
        grid->cells[col][row+1].north = piece_list->pieces[found].tab[SOUTH_TAB];
        grid->cells[col][row].west = piece_list->pieces[found].tab[WEST_TAB];
      }

    }

    /* Go to the next grid cell in the direction given as a parameter. */

    row += row_inc[inc_index];
    col += col_inc[inc_index];
  }
}

int
main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  int return_value = 0;
  piece_list_t piece_list;
  grid_t grid;
  int i, nthreads;

  if(sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &nthreads) != 1) {
    printf("Please input an integer");
    exit(1);
  }

  omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
  /* Solve the puzzle row by row starting with the top row. */
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
  for (i = 0; i < grid.numrows; i++) {
     fill_any_dir( &grid, &piece_list, 0, i, GO_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
  }

  return return_value;
}
```

So the first thing is to speed up the for loop in `main()`

```
for (i = 0; i < grid.numrows; i++) {
  fill_any_dir( &grid, &piece_list, 0, i, GO_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
}
```

I did get multi threads but the result was wrong, because this is supposed to go one by one (some dependencies). Is it possible to parallelize this for loop and output the result sequentially?

After this, I would like to parallelize the `while` loop in `fill_any_dir()` and the inner `for` loop, is it possible to parallelize both loops?

Comment: Do you want to parallelize this for the sake of writing parallel code, or to optimize the code?

Comment: Also, can you include the definitions of `piece_list_t` and `grid_t`.  Saying they're structs doesn't help us understand what sort of data structures you're using.

Comment: @Degustaf I want to parallelize the program to gain speed up, I have added the definitions

Comment: Is the problem that the results calculated from `fill_any_dir()` are incorrect when the code is parallelized or that you've got print statements which aren't shown in this questions that output the incorrect result?

Comment: @Kavanai4  that's because the data dependency in `fill_any_dir`, I don't know how to parallelize the for loop in `main()`